# How can return DateTime without change the format

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, culture

I have list of DateTimes, and I want to get DateTime with some format for show hours minutes seconds. For Example I have 4:32 PM 22 December 2015 from en-US culture and if I use bg-BG then to return 16:32 22 Декември (is mean December) 2015. Well is return 4:32 22 Декември 2015.

This is my simple code.

```
List<DateTime> xAxises = SetListOfDateTimes();
var culture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;

for (int i = 1; i <= xAxises.Count; i++)
{
    string someTime = xAxises.ElementAt(i - 1).ToString("hh:mm:ss tt", Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture);
    string anotherTime = xAxises.ElementAt(i - 1).ToString("ddd, dd MMMM hh:mm:ss tt", Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture);
    string thirdTime = xAxises.ElementAt(i - 1).ToString("dd MMMM yyyy", Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture);
    string fourthTime = xAxises.ElementAt(i - 1).ToString("MMMM yyyy", Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture);
}
```

My really problem is I have few DateTimes with bg-BG format and in `someTime` is return in en-US format. When `DateTime` is 21:22:30 the `someTime` is show me 9:22:30. I want to be 21:22:30. I put `tt` because is possible my application to used in United State if is culture in `en-US`.

Anybody to know how can return DateTime with current culture correctly.

Comment: Can you explain better what you're seeing? culture only comes into play when you're calling `.ToString(...)`, the DateTime itself does not have a culture per se. Have you looked at [NodaTime](http://nodatime.org/)?

Comment: The question doesn't make much sense. DateTime values *don't have any format or culture*. They are binary values, not strings. The culture used when formating on the other hand or parsing **is** the current culture. Please post code that shows what you tried, what you expected and what you got. What you postes is essentially identical to *not* passing any culture

Comment: BTW no culture uses 24 hours by default. I suspect the question isn't about cultures but custom formatting

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - daring assertion, we have 24 hour format here in Germany. In fact, I suppose, the 12 hour format is mainly used in english speaking countries.

Comment: @EvgeniVelikovevelikov Please make sure that either your system's culture *is* BG or post the code that changes the culture. If your culture *was* BG, you'd get `14:53` for eg `DateTime.Now.ToString("t")`, or `5.2.2016 г. 14:51:55` for `DateTime.Now.ToString()`. If you've set your development machine to an English locale though, you'd need to type `DateTime.Now.ToString("t",new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("bg-BG"))`

Comment: Is BG and what I read from list is in BG format, and in sometime is give me like en-US format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if you say you want 12 hour format, you get it. Try `HH` instead of `hh` (see [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)).

Or `ToLongTimeString()`. There are some more of these, `long` and `short` versions of `time` and `date, at least.

BTW, `DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString()` gives me `Freitag, 5. Februar 2016` without the need to explicitly specify a culture.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get time string in 24-hours format, you should use time format "HH:mm:ss" in ToString function. 
You can read more about date and time formatting here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx